# MsBuild Zip every file in directory in separate Zip files

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, msbuild-task

I have a folder with a large number of *.xml files.

I need all those files to be zipped each in a separate zip file.

Example:
- file1.xml
- file2.xml
- file3.xml

After msbuild:
- file1.zip
- file2.zip
- file3.zip

Note that I do not need to zip all the files within one ZIP, and the number of .xml files within the folder will vary everytime.

Is there anyway to do this with an automated msbuild task?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Zip task](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.4.0/html/f2118b59-554e-d745-5859-126a82b1df81.htm) from [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/). Then your MSBuild target can be something like:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="ZipFiles">

  <UsingTask TaskName="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip"
           AssemblyFile="..\MSBuildExtensionPack\Releases\4.0.4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll"  />

  <Target Name="ZipFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToZip Include="xmls\**\*.xml"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="Zipping '%(FilesToZip.Identity)'" Importance="high" />
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip TaskAction="Create"
                                           CompressFiles="%(FilesToZip.FullPath)"
                                           ZipFileName="%(FilesToZip.Filename).zip"
                                           RemoveRoot="%(FilesToZip.RootDir)%(FilesToZip.Directory)" />

  </Target>  

</Project>
```